# node js dump sql as xlsx or csv fastest possible way

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, csv, node-mysql

I have a mysql database that has close to 1 million rows. I am using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) to get the data from db which takes about 4-5 seconds (expected as I am running multiple joins). However, when I try to dump this data into xlsx using [js-xlsx writer](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/19c22fa34af4ec92f1984dae9fce8f749a39aac6/tests/write.js), it takes forever (10-15 minutes or more) as `sheet_from_array_of_arrays` function reads each row one by one. If anyone knows how to make it faster, please do let me know.

Also, if anyone else knows any other faster way to dump mysql db to csv or xls or xlsx?

Thanks

Comment: Make a CSV file instead and use the streaming interfaces for node-mysql and node-csv.

Comment: well, for fastest way... i thinking of simply exporting the table as csv using sql cmd: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

Comment: you asked for node so assuming you're doing some post-processing, but yeah, doing the dump as a CSV would be best direct from mysql

Comment: ya, i am sorry for the confusion... yes, i finally am sending xlsx/csv to client as response, but i don't need any processing... i think i am good with simply dumping mysql as csv. thanks

Comment: but however, it will be good to know which csv writer node library i can use?

Comment: [node-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv)